# Header from modal from GoRatchet appear on page

Tags: ratchet-2

I dont use HEADER in my app, only in modal. After some click on bar-tab, header from modal appear on page. Can some tell my how to fix this?
[Bug img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvwYA.png)

Answer (score 0):

Resolve: move `<modal>` from `<div class="content">.`

Erorr include: I placed `<modal>` in `<div class="content">`.